# Are questions on Developer Experience off-topic on DevOps?

Tags: support, questions

Is Developer Experience (as related to the culture DevOps facet I suppose?) off-topic here?

Examples:

- *Would the strategy/methodology to qualify the level of Developer Experience significantly differ from strategies/methodologies known in the User Experience domain, applied to a given DevOps tool's UI?*
- *How to formalize Developer Experience qualification strategy/methodology in DevOps toolsets where core asset is interaction with a tool's  API?*

To the second point, I may pay attention to situations where developer community discussing more or less their UX-related feeling, hope these examples are common: "this call is ugly".. "I am not comfortable with this interface".. "I don't like tool X"..

Specific problem: DX is a new field; working assumption is that good DX could make engineers happy as we know it from good UX. But it is not clear how to proceed (or if it comes out that such questions on DevOps are off topic the assumption is wrong and DX is rather a 'bad meme'.

Comment: Possible to cite an example please? :)

Comment: @Dawny33 - here you go, thank you for motivating me to work on crystallzing the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that I was part of a team called Software Experience, targeted at human experience for the personnel involved in many aspects of the SDLC process (devs, ops, QA/testers, etc). Tools' UX was included, of course, but also other stuff much more DevOps-y, for example:

- developer's workflow
- process automation
- service waiting times
- tools and infrastructure status, availability, MTRR, event notifications

So yeah, I'd say such questions would be very on-topic. Though, to be fair, similarly Ops (and QA/Tester) experience questions should be on-topic just as well.